# Gradle compiling android.jar error -> It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm compiling with `gradlew assembleRelease` in a Linux server with console (no visual interface available).

When compiling this error is shown a lot of times:

```
Err:It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
Err:warning: /Users/mo/Documents/android-sdk/platforms/android-22/android.jar(android/text/SpannableString.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
```

Does this mean that I must update Java installed on this server? How can this be done with command line in a Linux machine?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK *major version* means Java version. Java 7 is 51, Java 6 is 50. The code is written for Java 7, I guess? So to make this error go away, I suppose you should do the following:

1. Update to Java 7 by your system package manager (you may want to look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/linux/linux-jdk.html) and [here](http://www.placona.co.uk/171/linux/updating-java-on-centos/) to get some idea how to do it).

   In general, all you need is to perform some `yum install java-1.7.*-openjdk` to get newer version, but in some cases things could be a bit more difficult. You didn't tell us which Linux are you using.
2. Add this to your `build.gradle`:

   ```
   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
   }
   ```

And make sure that your `$JAVA_HOME` points to new Java version. That's it.